# Taylor series for cosine around $\pi/3$

Tags: taylor-expansion

I need the Taylor-Series for $ f(x) = \cos(x) $ in $ a = \pi/3$:

\begin{align*}
f(x)
&= \cos(x - \pi/3 + \pi/3) \\
&= \cos \left( x - \frac{\pi}{3}\right)  \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right) - \sin\left(x-\frac{\pi}{3}\right) \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n  \frac{(x-\frac{\pi}{3})^{2n}}{(2n)!}  - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n  \frac{(x-\frac{\pi}{3})^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}
\end{align*}

Am I right so far? I'm not sure how to make this expression "easier" and to get the convergence ratio. =/

Comment: try to differentiate according to this formula  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series

Comment: What exactly do you mean? :)

Comment: Yes, this looks perfect to me. The convergence is the same as for the series for $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$, i.e. it converges everywhere.

Comment: You found a good way. Technically, it is not quite right, since you need to arrange things in increasing powers of $x-\pi/3$. Another way as suggested in the comment above is to use the definition, the derivatives are easy. The Ratio Test will work fine for convergence.

Comment: Hi! When using the derivates I get $ cos(x) = cos(\pi/3) - \frac{sin(\pi/3)\cdot(x-\pi/3)}{1!} - ... = 1/2 - \frac{\sqrt{3}\cdot(x-\pi/3)}{2} - \frac{x-\pi/3)^2}{2\cdot2!} ...$ ??? Is there any way fo find a nicer expression now? WIthout I don't know how to do the Ratio Test.

Comment: that is a good answer. i think i might have been rather thrown by the question.

Comment: The bouncing around constants don't matter much. When you find $|a_{n+1}/a_n|$, you get $\frac{e_n}{n+1}$, where $e_n$ is $\sqrt{3}$ or $1/\sqrt{3}$. So $|a_{n+1}/a_n|\lt \sqrt{3}/(n+1)$, which goes nicely to $0$. Ratio Test says we have convergence for all $x$.

Comment: Well.. I'm afraid I really can't find $|a_{n+1}/a_n| $ . How do I start? Since I couldn't find any way to express my $a_n$ I'm really not sure what to do now :( Would be great if you can help once again :)

Answer (score 1):

"simplification" is sometimes down to taste but sometimes also to the needs of a situation. i think you might be looking for something along the following lines:

$$
\text{set   }\; \xi(n) = \frac12(\chi_2(n+1) + \sqrt{3}\chi_2(n+2))
$$

here $\chi_2$ is the second Dirichlet character of modulus 4, which cycles through the values $0,+1,0,-1$

then
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \xi(n)  \frac{(x-\frac{\pi}{3})^{n}}{n!} 
$$
this brilliant piece of technique was introduced by Dirichlet in his (successful) attempt to prove that there are an infinite number of primes in any arithmetic progression $a+bn$ when $(a,b)=1$

note added for OP: the ratio of $\mid a_{n+1} \mid$ to $\mid a_n \mid$ is less than: 
$$
2 \frac{\mid{x-\frac{\pi}{3}}\mid}{n+1}
$$

Comment: wow.. Ok I will take a closter look at this, thanks! And how can I not find out the convergence ratio?

Comment: you will see that $\forall\; n \; \text{we have} \frac12 \le \mid \xi(n) \mid \le \frac{\sqrt{3}}2$

Comment: EDIT: Okay, I not understood so far. But what do I have to do next?

Comment: now you have a closed form for the terms you can apply one of the tests for convergence. the ratio test is not so esoteric as it may look, since it is based on showing that a series is eventually dominated in absolute value of terms by a convergent geometric series, $1+\rho+\rho^2+\dots$ the bounds on $\xi$ mean, effectively, that you may treat it as a constant and forget about it, so can you, as a first step, evaluate the (absolute value of) the ratio of the terms for $n=m+1$ and $n=m$?